# About Dijkstra omp

Tags: c, openmp

Recently I've download a [`source code`](http://read.pudn.com/downloads158/sourcecode/mpi/701935/Dijkstra-omp.c__.htm) from internet of the `OpenMP Dijkstra`.

But I found that the parallel time will always larger than when it is run by one thread (whatever I use two, four or eight threads.)

Since I'm new to OpenMP I really want to figure out what happens.

Comment: Probably overhead, for small inputs you spend more time on creating/managing the threads than on actual computation.

Answer (score 0):

The is due to the overheard of setting up the threads. The execution time of the work itself is theoretically the same, but the system has to set up the threads that manage the work (even if there's only one). For little work, or for only one thread, this overhead time makes your time-to-solution slower than the serial time-to-solution.

Alternatively, if you see the time increasing dramatically as you increase the thread-count, you could only be using 1 core on your computer and tricking it into thinking its 2,4,8, etc threads.

Finally, it's possible that the way you're implementing dijkstra's method is largely serial. But without looking at your code it would be too hard to say.